# Hover over cell in table to display entire String in one line, centered

Tags: css, hover, css-tables

I have a table with cells that display a lot of data of varying lengths, some of which get cut off because the string is too long to fit into the column (this is fine).  I would like to add the functionality to center and display the entire String in one line when hovering over a particular cell, covering columns to the right/left if necessary.

Using white-space:nowrap keeps the text in one line, but causes the hovered text to run into/behind the cell to the right, resulting in a jumbled mess of two strings.  Also, the hover background color only goes as far as the original cell width.  (I have tried setting the width to something larger, and it doesn't change anything.)

Using white-space:normal allows me to view the whole String (as it wraps the text), and the hover background color dynamically expands to cover the entire expanded cell, but I do not want the cell to expand in height and push rows below it down.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Since I didn't know what your initial data was I went ahead and just made a small table with some extended data. Here is an example of what your looking for if I read your question correctly.

Not CSS - If you were to use just CSS you would have to hook hover then apply styles accordingly. Not sure what yours looks like so I won't screw your table up.

http://jsfiddle.net/zWfac/

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <th>Header 0</th><th>Header 1</th>
            <tr>
                <td>0,0 - My extended content that doesn't fit in the table</td> <td>0,1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,0</td> <td>1,1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2,0</td> <td>2,1 - More extended content!</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript + JQuery

```
var container = $("#container");

$("td").hover(function ()
              {
                  container.children(".tooltip").remove(); 

                  var element = $(this);
                  var offset = element.offset();
                  var toolTip = $("<div class='tooltip'></div>");

                  toolTip.css(
                      {
                          top : offset.top,
                          left : offset.left
                      });

                  toolTip.text(element.text());
                  container.append(toolTip);
              });
```

CSS

```
tr
{
    width: 100%;
}

td, th
{
    width: 65px;
    max-width: 65px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tooltip
{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background-color: tan;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're going for? I'm using jQuery to dynamically resize the `td` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('td').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('max-width', 'inherit');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('max-width', '100px');
  }) 

});
```